# Bringing back the tab bar after pushing a view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In the iPhone app I'm making, there's a UINavigationController that can drill down one layer to another view controller.

On the top-most view controller, I hide the Tab Bar with this line...

```
TopViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

... in the app delegate.  Then, from the TopViewController, the user can push a UIButton that will take them down to another ViewController, in which I **do not** want to hide the tab bar.

I tried adding this line in viewDidLoad in the second-level view controller, but it doesn't work:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Does anyone know how I can bring my tab bar back?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> Discussion
>   If YES, the bar at the bottom of the screen is hidden; otherwise, NO. If YES, the bottom bar remains hidden until the view controller is popped from the stack.

But can you try setting the value to `YES` in the action method for your button? Right before you push the new view controller in place.